# JQuery Cycle and Title Image

Tags: jquery, jcycle

I need help,
I would like to change the title in a div when rotating the image.

```
$('.pics').cycle({
fx:     'fade',
timeout: 6000,
after:   function() {
    var title = $('.image').attr('alt');
    $('.image_title').html(title);
}
});
```

....

```
<div class="pics"> 
<img src="01.jpg" alt="Picture 1" class="image"/>
    <img src="02.jpg" alt="Picture 2" class="image"/>
    <img src="03.jpg" alt="Picture 3" class="image"/>
</div>
<div class="image_title"></div>
```

but this does not work, it displays only the first attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive the only thing you'll need to change is to use the `$(this)` keyword in order to reference the current image item.

```
after:   function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.image_title').html(title);
}
```

Every time you executed `$('.image').attr('alt');`, all you got was the `alt` property of the first element that matches the selector. `$('.image')` could very well match several elements on your page.